# Need to form pattern for regexp_replace

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have input string something like :

```
1.2.3.4_abc_4.2.1.44_1.3.4.23
100.11.11.22_xyz-abd_10.2.1.2_12.2.3.4
100.11.11.22_xyz_123_10.2.1.2_1.2.3.4
```

I have to replace the first string formed between two ipaddress which are separated by `_`, however in some string the `_` is part of the replacement string (`xyz_123`)

I have to find the abc, xyz-abd and xyz_123 from the above string, so that I can replace with another column in that table.

Answer (score 2):

```
_.*?_(?=\d+\.)
```

matches `_abc_`, `_xyz-abd_` and `_xyz_123_` in your examples. Is this working for you?

```
DECLARE
    result VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    result := REGEXP_REPLACE(subject, $$_.*?_(?=\d+\.)$$, $$_foo_$$);
END;
```

Comment: How to add "_" to the replacement column , for eg : update table1 set column1=regexp_replace(column1,'_.*?_(?=\d+\.)',column2) , here i have to add column2 with "_" , but not sure how to do

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is enough:

```
_[^.]+_
```

and replace with

```
_Replacement_
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?38bhk).

`[^.]+` uses a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match a sequence of at least one ([the `+` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) non "." characters.

I am also matching a leading and a trailing "_", so you have to put it in again in the replacement string.

**If `PostgreSQL` supports [lookbehind and lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), then it is possible to avoid the "_" in the replacement string**:

```
(?<=_)[^.]+(?=_)
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?38bic)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, is it possible to avoid "_" for the replacement string

Comment: @Ayush, that depends on what PostgreSQL supports. Improved my answer.

Comment: It seems that postgres do not support the later regex which you have provided, any help on how to add "_" with column , i tried with "_"+column2+"_" , but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

In order to map match first two "*" , as @stema and @Tim Pietzcker mentioned the regex works. Then in order to append "*" to the column , which is what I was struggling with, can be done with || operator as eg below

update table1 set column1=regexp_replace(column1,'.*?*(?=\d+.)','*' || column2 || '_')

Then for using the another table for update query , the below eg can be helpfull

update table1 as t set column1=regexp_replace(column1,'.*?*(?=\d+.)','*' || column2 || '_') from table2  as t2 where t.id=t2.id [other criteria]